# How to get data which has expiry date nearest to current date?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-query-builder

I have `PurchaseOrderProduct` Model from which I am getting data like that

```
PurchaseOrderProduct::with('products')
                     ->with('warehouse_locations')
                     ->with('productStatuses')
                     ->with('purchase_orders')
                     ->where('product_id', $request->product_id)
                     ->where('free_qty', '>=', 1)
                     ->get();
```

Now in this table, I have the column `expiry_date` of type `date` i want to fetch data `orderBy` `expiry_date` nearest to the current date .

Means `purchase_order_product` whose expiry date is nearest to current date should come first.

Comment: Do you need expired products in your results or can they be excluded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$product = PurchaseOrderProduct::with('products')
           ->with('warehouse_locations')
           ->with('productStatuses')
           ->with('purchase_orders')
           ->where('product_id', $request->product_id)
           ->where('free_qty', '>=', 1)
           ->whereDate('expiry_date', '>', Carbon::now())
           ->orderBy('expiry_date','asc')
           ->get();
```